# Standard C or Python libraries to compute standard deviation of normal distribution

Tags: python, c, algorithm, math, probability

Say we have normal distribution n(x): mean=0 and \int_{-a}^{a} n(x) = P.

What is the easiest way to compute standard deviation of such distribution? May be there are standard libraries for python or C, that are suitable for that task?

Comment: Isn't the standard deviation of a normal distribution with a mean of 0, always 1.0?  Isn't that the definition?

Comment: That's only true of a standard normal distribution, I think.

Comment: P=\int_{-a}^{a} n(x) should be 1, or else it's not a probability distribution. The standard distribution (or variance) can be anything, though.

Comment: The univariate normal density is defined over the whole real line. The integral from -infinity to +infinity should be 1, the integral from -a to a should not.

Comment: Right, sorry. Don't know why I read "a" as "∞" :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard deviation of a mean-zero gaussian distribution with Pr(-a < X < a) = P is

```
a/(sqrt(2)*inverseErf(P))
```

which is the expression you're looking for, where inverseErf is the inverse of the error function (commonly known as erf).

For C, the Gnu Scientific Library (GSL) is a good resource.  However it only has erf, not inverseErf, so you'd have to invert it yourself (a simple binary search would do the trick).  Alternatively, here's a nice way to approximate erf and inverseErf:

http://homepages.physik.uni-muenchen.de/~Winitzki/erf-approx.pdf

For Python, inverseErf is available as `erfinv` in the SciPy library, so the following gives the standard deviation:

```
a/(math.sqrt(2)*erfinv(P))
```

PS: There's some kind of bug in Stackoverflow's URL rendering and it wouldn't let me link to GSL above:  http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl.
It also renders wrong when I make the URL above with a pdf a proper link.

Answer (score 7):

If X is normal with mean 0 and standard deviation sigma, it must hold

```
P = Prob[ -a <= X <= a ] = Prob[ -a/sigma <= N <= a/sigma ]
  = 2 Prob[ 0 <= N <= a/sigma ]
  = 2 ( Prob[ N <= a/sigma ] - 1/2 )
```

where N is normal with mean 0 and standard deviation 1. Hence

```
P/2 + 1/2 = Prob[ N <= a/sigma ] = Phi(a/sigma)
```

Where Phi is the cumulative distribution function (cdf) of a normal variable with mean 0 and stddev 1. Now we need the *inverse* normal cdf (or the "percent point function"), which in Python is scipy.stats.norm.ppf(). Sample code:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
P = 0.3456
a = 3.0

a_sigma = float(norm.ppf(P/2 + 0.5))   # a/sigma
sigma = a/a_sigma   # Here is the standard deviation
```

For example, we know that the probability of a N(0,1) variable falling int the interval [-1.1] is ~ 0.682 (the dark blue area in [this figure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image:Standard_deviation_diagram.svg)). If you set P = 0.682 and a = 1.0 you obtain sigma ~ 1.0, which is indeed the standard deviation.

Answer (score 3):

[SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/) has a [stats](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/#scipy-organization) sub-package.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [sciPy Project](http://scipy.org/), it should have what you need.